# Arduino sketch example work OK, when export to Atmel Studio 7 solution, then get errors as: 'WDT' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, atmelstudio

I run a example of SSD1306 lirary in IDE Arduino, specifics:
https://github.com/lexus2k/ssd1306/tree/master/examples/demos/ssd1306_demo

I can build and run over Arduino Nano board using Arduino IDE.
But I like work with Atmel Studio 7, is the best IDE!, then I import the sketch ssd1306_demo.ino to Atmel Studio using File -> New Project -> Create Project from Arduino Sketch.
When I finalice the process, I try build the solution, and get severals erros:

**Build Error**

[image]

I realice the process with others Arduino examples Sketch and work fine all times, but for this specific project, not work.

Any idea to solve the issue?

Thanks Very much.
César